# Suggestion to upgrade from 2.332.3 to latest LTS version(2.440.1)

Tags: jenkins, upgrade

We want to upgrade a Jenkins instance from 2.332.2 (from May 2022) to 2.440.1 (2024). Because this is such a large jump of LTS versions - we were planning to do a rolling upgrade by upgrading to every other LTS version until we reach 2.440.1 .

Is there a strategy recommended for this type of upgrade? Not sure if this is the right approach. Thanks in advance.

upgrade a Jenkins instance from 2.332.2 (from May 2022) to 2.440.1 (2024)

Comment: use https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/

everything else is up to you, i'd jump to latest and fix issues one time instead of fixing one by one